# Fatal Python Error

Tags: python, sql-server, visual-studio

Hola descargue la versión 3.7.0 de 64 bits y la estoy usando en *Visual Code Estudio*. cuando la abro en símbolo del sistema y lo trato de ejecutar me sale esta error:

> Fatal Python error: initfsencoding: unable to load the file system codec
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'encodings'
>
> Current thread 0x00002320 (most recent call first):

Y también cuando lo abro desde *Visual Code* lo ejecuta desde el servidor de SQL.

¿Cómo puedo evitar eso para que se tarde menos?

Answer (score 0):

Es probable que python no esté agregado al PATH de windows correctamente.
Proba con estos pasos.

1. Toca el boton de inicio y busca "Editar las variables de entorno del sistema"
2. Hacé click abajo a la derecha en variables de entorno
3. En la ventana que se abre, en el panel de "**Variables del sistema** buscá la variable llamada **Path** y clickea en editar.
4. Por último dale click a nuevo y pone la ubicación donde tengas instalado python, ejemplo **C:\Program Files\Python36**.

Con esto se deberia solucionar.